# C# HTML Agility Pack (not/wrong) iterating over node collection

Tags: c#, collections, foreach, html-agility-pack

im using HTML Agility Pack to fetch URLs from w webpage. The URL is:

http://goo.gl/DqfQl

If i use the code below i get the links i want:

```
String html = getHtml("http://goo.gl/DqfQl");

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

doc.LoadHtml(html);

HtmlNodeCollection address_rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='name']/a"); 

foreach (HtmlNode row in address_rows)
{
    MessageBox.Show(row.GetAttributeValue("href",LINK_NOT_FOUND));
}
```

But when i change the `HtmlNodeCollection` to fetch the containg `div` with `class="row'` and the want to fetch the URL i get always the first URL.

```
HtmlNodeCollection address_rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='row']"); 

foreach (HtmlNode element in address_rows) {
    MessageBox.Show(element.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='name']/a").GetAttributeValue("href",LINK_NOT_FOUND));
}
```

I played a little with this code and for a while i thought i worked. But now i cant using the second code snippet select all the URLs i want. Can you help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to add a dot "." to the XPath, otherwise it wil match from the beginning of the Document and not inside the node.

Just change your second string to `".//div[@class='name']/a"` and it should work

Comment: Big Thx. It works. Is there a good documentation for HAP? I searched 5 mins on Google, but could not find anything useful.

Comment: It's easier to look for a good xpath tutorial, everything that works with xpath also does for the agilitypack. a good place to get started is http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/

Comment: oh, and there's also the HAP Testbed which let's you load html and test your xpaths http://haptestbed.codeplex.com/

Comment: @RobertNiestroj Its too late, but here is a document I found while trying to resolve the same problem.
https://librarycarpentry.org/lc-webscraping/02-xpath/index.html